# Winform C# Update DataGridView on DataTable Cell value changed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have DataGridView and DataTable, DataTable is assigned as a datasource in DataGridView.

When I change some value in DataTable it is not update on the view.

So How can i achive this

I have tried following things

1. BindingSource
2. Refresh()

Demo Code

```
DataGridView datagrid = new DataGridView();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("No");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
     DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
     row[0] = i;
     row[1] = "ABC";
     dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

datagrid.DataSource = dt;
```

Here my above code

When i change some value in DataTable it is not reflect in DataGridView

```
dt.Rows[0][1] = "XYZ";
```

So Please help me....

Comment: In what event are you changing the value?

Comment: @thewisegod some button click event i change value in datatable

Comment: How do you get a reference to the datatable from inside the click event? Is the datatable declared at page level?

Comment: I am working on Winform App, and DataTable declared as Member variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do this, which works:

```
private DataTable _dt = new DataTable();  

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    _dt.Columns.Add("LongText");
    DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "One";
    _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr = _dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "Two";
    _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr = _dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "Three";
    _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = _dt;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _dt.Rows[0][0] = "daddy";
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to do this.. in this way but don't know why it isn't working for me

Comment: So is your code set up like this? If it is then that is definitely weird.

Comment: Please DatagridView Datasource set part do in button click event..then it is working?

Comment: yup almost but i am not assigning datasource in form load event

Comment: Could you please post your exact setup? Also in the code above, if I move the Datasource assignment to the button click, I see "daddy" instead of "One" as expected.

Comment: I think i have done some mistake somewhere so i need to found that
and Your solution are correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your datagrid to your form, like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView datagrid = new DataGridView();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //add this line
        Controls.Add(datagrid);

        dt.Columns.Add("No");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = i;
            row[1] = "ABC";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        datagrid.DataSource = dt;

        dt.Rows[0][1] = "XYZ";
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I added datagridview into the form via designer

Comment: Ok... but your code shows datagrid being created in code behind, not through the designer: `DataGridView datagrid = new DataGridView();`